# Why does the process of energy extraction from a black hole take place with maximum efficiency when entropy remains constant?

Tags: black-holes, black-hole-thermodynamics

I read in a book that as black holes lose energy their radius decreases: this should lead to a decrease in the area of the black hole, therefore entropy should decrease. Hence the doubt.